# URL with trailing slash does not load scripts and CSS in PHP site

Tags: apache

what is the difference between these two URLs:

```
abc.com/company-profile.php
abc.com/company-profile.php/
```

When I directly open the first one (without trailing slash) the page open perfectly.

But when search it in Google I get the second link (with trailing slash) and when I click on this link, the page only shows code, no script or css included.

After clicking on any `style.css`, the page shows like `abc.com/company-profile.php/css/style.css`.

What is happening?

Comment: how is created your website ? With Wordpress or another CMS ? If you can give us your website's public url, will help us to help you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The cause can be that Google indexes your website with a sitemap.xml file having the `company-profile.php/` url and not `company-profile.php`.

And unfortunately your website doesn't manage well the trailing slash at the end of the url (you can fix this with updating .htaccess file)

You have to check the sitemap generated and downloaded by Google.
The url's sitemap name differs according you are using Wordpress, Drupal or another CMS, or a custom website...